# Unable to get nginx/php-fpm consistently working with docker-compose and a custom wordpress install

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm honestly just getting quite frustrated. I feel like I keep fiddling with my nginx conf, and I'll get it working, until I restart my PC or docker. All of the docker functionality seems to be working fine, I can build and `docker-compose up` without problem, but it seems like every time I restart my computer or docker I have to fiddle with my nginx conf again until it works. I'm using wordpress, and currently have wordpress installed to a subdirectory `wp` and my wp-content in a different subdirectory at `content`.

My nginx configuration looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www;
    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/index.php /index.php;

      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

and it was working yesterday while I was working, but after restarting the PC overnight, and trying to work on the site today, I'm getting the standard php-fpm issue `FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown"`. I'm just curious if anybody has a solution, or knows why I'm having this issue. I understand that the "Primary script unknown" error usually means that my SCRIPT_FILENAME param is bad, but it was working yesterday, and as far as I can tell should always point to `/var/www/index.php`, which is where my wordpress index file is.

Should I basically just hardcode $document_root/index.php ?

**EDIT: I literally just rebuilt my docker containers with `docker-compose build` and everything is working as intended. So I guess this question is more associated with docker than nginx/php, but I would still love some guidance. Would there be some reason my docker containers are ephemeral and need rebuilding on boot everytime?**

Comment: It looks like your containers didn't start after PC had been booted up. If yes, just add `restart policy: always` to your docker-compose file.

Comment: Do the containers not automatically get started when you run docker-compose up?

Comment: According to the https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart : `no` is the default restart policy, and it does not restart a container under any circumstance.